# Parsing complex JSON with Go

Tags: json, parsing, go

I'm having issues digesting some nested JSON with Go. My primary issue is that I can't model my struct correctly to try and get the library to pull any information in. Here is a sample of the JSON data: http://pastebin.com/fcGQqi5z

The data is from a bank and has been scrubbed for privacy. Ideally I'm only interested in the transactions ID, the amount, and the description. Is there a way to just pull these values with Go?

This was my initial attempt:

```
type Trans struct {
  TransId string
  Amount int
  Description string
}
```

Comment: can you post valid json please that can be easily copy/pasted?

Comment: Updated the pastebin with valid Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right tracks:

```
type Trans struct {
    TransId     string
    Amount      float64
    Description string
}

func main() {
    var data struct {
        Record []Trans
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", data.Record)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/hxbM0q-KMd)

//edit

```
type Trans struct {
    TransId     string
    Amount      float64
    Description string
    RawInfo     []map[string]json.RawMessage `json:"AdditionalInfo"`
}

// also this assumes that 1. all data are strings and 2. they have unique keys
// if this isn't the case, you can use map[string][]string or something
func (t *Trans) AdditionalInfo() (m map[string]string) {
    m = make(map[string]string, len(t.RawInfo))
    for _, info := range t.RawInfo {
        for k, v := range info {
            m[k] = string(v)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/PP_aFbWCkL)

Comment: Since Amount and Description are nested in "AdditionalInfo" how does the parser know to grab it without explicitly telling it that they are located inside "AdditionalInfo" ?

Comment: I stand corrected. Just for learning sake, how would I incorporate any details inside "AdditionalInfo"?

Comment: @JoshuaGilman I updated the post, basically since `AdditionalData` has no real format, you can use `[]map[string]string` or `[]map[string]json.RawMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

```
type Records struct {
    Records []Record `json:"record"`
}

type Record struct {
    TransId string
    Amount float64
    Description string
}

func main() {
    r := Records{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &r); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(r)
}
```